# Cast 0 count on mondays by week when no data is returned, SQL

Tags: sql-server, date, casting, count

I am trying to write an sql query that will return a count of all products started by week. The date is by every monday. So each row will return the monday of that week and the total count of units started that week. The total amount of weeks need to be for every week in the current quarter the report is ran. I have this code, however when no units are created that week then the data is missing. I need to return a 0 on weeks that have no units started instead of it just not being there. I found some sources online but they mostly used a "generate_series" command that my SSMS doesn't seem to have.

Example Data: tableA

```
Product--------DateStarted-----
1              2019-10-2
1              2019-10-4
1              2019-10-3
1              2019-10-23
1              2019-11-08
1              2019-11-09
```

### -

Desired Result:

```
 Week----------Product Count
 2019-09-30    3
 2019-10-07    0
 2019-10-14    0
 2019-10-21    1
 .....Continued 0s for each week with the date being monday
 2019-11-04    2
 ...continued to end of quarter
 2019-12-30     0
```

### -

Current result:

```
  Week------------ProductCount-----
  2019-09-30      3
  2019-10-21      1
  2019-11-04      2
```

### -

Current SQL Code

```
SELECT Count([week]) as 'TotalStarted', [week] FROM 
(SELECT 
DATEADD(DAY, 2 -DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Crated),  CAST(DateStarted as date)) as 'Week' 
FROM tableA 
WHERE Product like ('1') 
AND [DateStarted] >= DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND 
[DateStarted] <= DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) +1, 0))) tbla 
Group by [Week]
```

Comment: You'll need to create a table variable (or temp table or permanent table for that matter) that contains all of the weeks you're interested in.  There are a lot of example everywhere on how to do that (manually, recursive CTE, while loop).  After you create the table containing every Monday you simply start with that table and left join your query as a subquery.  The left join is what will show the "missing" weeks.

Comment: @avery_larry sorry for the long response, got into a meeting. I am going to try and make an independent table and do a join on it. Ill post my results.

Answer (score 0):

Use having

```
SELECT Count([week]) as 'TotalStarted', [week] FROM 
(SELECT 
DATEADD(DAY, 2 -DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Crated),  CAST(DateStarted as date)) as 'Week' 
FROM tableA 
WHERE Product like ('1') 
AND [DateStarted] >= DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND 
[DateStarted] <= DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) +1, 0))) tbla 
Group by [Week]
HAVING Count([week])>0
```

Sorry I really misread it.
Try something like this. *In fact it's the avery_larry's answer*
If think you have to adapt the representative day of the week

```sql
;WITH [0 to 12] (v) as 
(
SELECT V
FROM (
  VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5) ,(6), (7), (8), (9), (11), (12) 
)T(V)
),
[date_in_qq] (week) as (
    SELECT DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()),0)),v*7)
    FROM [0 to 12]
)
SELECT Count(tbla.[week]) as 'TotalStarted', [date_in_qq].[week] FROM 
[date_in_qq] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT 
DATEADD(DAY, 2 -DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Crated),  CAST(DateStarted as date)) as 'Week' 
FROM tableA 
WHERE Product like ('1') 
AND [DateStarted] >= DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND 
[DateStarted] <= DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) +1, 0))) 
tbla ON tbla.[week] = [date_in_qq].[week]
Group by [date_in_qq].[Week]
```